# PHP How to create array value using for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

PHP How to create array value using for loop ?

```
$my_array=array(
   for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
      {
         $i,
      }
);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($my_array); echo '<pre/>';
```

Comment: why dont you try the range(1,10) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$my_array = array();
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
            $my_array[]= $i;
}
```

Comment: Please also explain the code you are throwing around.

Answer (score 5):

Simple for number arrays.

```
$my_array = range(0, 10);
```

If you want to add increment more then 1 you can

```
$step = 2;
$my_array = range(0, 10, $step);
```

[See here](https://www.php.net/range)

Answer (score 2):

```
$my_array=array();
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
$my_array[]=$i;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop after the array declaration

```
<?php
$my_array=array();
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
   $my_array[] = $i;
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($my_array); echo '<pre/>';
?>
```